# View placeholders replacement with xib using the awakeAfterUsingCoder method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

I am currently working on an iOS app that has multiple xibs containing a UIView subclass which is acting as a placeholder for the header of the screen.
When the view controllers are loaded from their nib, they instantiate the HeaderView placeholder. In the HeaderView class I have a method that replace the placeholder view by the real one, here is the code :

```
- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (![[self subviews] count])
    {
        if (headerViewNib == nil)
            headerViewNib = [UINib frameworkNibWithNibName: @"HeaderView"];

        HeaderView * headerView = [[headerViewNib instantiateWithOwner: controller options: nil] lastObject];

        [headerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

        return headerView;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Until now, everything works correctly. But now I need to add a menu similar to a popover to the header. So I added a UIButton to the HeaderView xib, as expected it is showing in all the view controllers, but now I need to manage the touch on that button.
I added a "- (IBAction)showHeaderMenu" method to my base UIViewController class, and I configured in the HeaderView.xib the file's owner to this class, so I could connect the button touch action, to the showHeaderMenu action.
The problem is that I am passing "controller" as owner to the instantiateWithOwner:options: method. But this controller is nil. So my touch events on the menu button are not handled.

So now I am searching a way to get the "controller" property set correctly. At the moment in all my view controllers xib, I connected the placeholder headerview "controller" outlet to the file's owner (which is the controller), but it does not seems to be working.

If you have a different pattern to suggest, that does not force me to drop my HeaderView.xib or the placeholders view, i'm open :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i get exactly your problem but if it is related to your not being able to set up the IBAction through IB because something is not loaded or whatever you can always setup the IBAction event listener through code.

```
UIButton *yourButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

Comment: Yes, it can be an option, even if I would like to avoid adding code to connect one button to its action method while IB is doing it for all my other controls. Also, at the moment the target seems connected since I get a "message sent to deallocated instance" crash when touching the button, but I don't know to what it is connected :)

Comment: Actually I don't understand why my placeholder header's outlet which is connected to the File's owner (the controller) is not decoded from the nib. I looked at the .xib source code, and it is connected like that "<outlet property="controller" destination="-1" id="eJ2-z7-nLM"/>", and I see the same XML for the collection views delegate/datasource, searchbar delegate etc... and these links are correctly decoded.